# Get a value of an attribute by XPath and HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a HTML document and I parse it with XPath. I want to get a value of the element input, but it didn't work.

My Html:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="item" value="10743" readonly="readonly" size="10"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

My code:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc; 
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlNodeCollection node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input/@value");
string s=node[0].InnerText;
```

So **I want to get the value: "10743"** (and I don't mind to get another tags with the answer.)

Comment: No, because I want to get the value by the `node[0].InnerText`

Comment: But an attribute does not have an `InnerText`.

Comment: Yes, that my problem because I must use `InnerText` because this is in loop, But I don't mind to get the whole text include the element. `<td> <input type="text" name="item" value="10743" readonly="readonly" size="10"/> </td>`. But how?

Comment: I guess you are not getting my point. You are selecting _attributes_. These only have a `Value`, not an `InnerText`.

Comment: Yes, I Caught it, but Is there no other way? a trick or something like that? Even get another tags that I don't need, in addition to the value. So the element will be innerText of another tag.

Comment: @Chanipoz: You forgot to tell us what exactly you want to get as the result of evaluating the XPAth expression: an object, a string,..., what exactly string...?

Comment: I added in the question what I exactly want.

Comment: @Chanipoz: Could you, please, provide the complete C# code and the complete HTML document? From the code snippet it sems that you aren't using HtmlAgilityPack at all.

Answer (score 17):

you can get it in `.Attributes` collection:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.html");
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input") [0];
var val = node.Attributes["value"].Value; //10743
```

Answer (score 7):

**Update2**: Here is a code example how to get values of attributes using Html Agility Pack:

**http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples**

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

You obviously need to adapt this code to your needs -- for example you will not modify the attributes, but will just use `att.Value` .

---

**Update**: You may also look at this question:

**[Selecting attribute values with html Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541953/selecting-attribute-values-with-html-agility-pack)**

---

**Your problem is most likely a default namespace problem** -- search for "XPath  default namespace c#" and you will find many good solutions (hint: use the overload of **[`SelectNodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx)** that has an **[`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx)** argument).

**The following code shows what one gets for an attribute in a document in** "no namespace":

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<input value='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
                    "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
                    "</input>");

        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNode value = doc.SelectNodes("//input/@value")[0];

        Console.WriteLine("Inner text: " + value.InnerText);
        Console.WriteLine("InnerXml: " + value.InnerXml);
        Console.WriteLine("OuterXml: " + value.OuterXml);
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value.Value);

    }
}
```

**The result from running this app is**:

```
Inner text: novel
InnerXml: novel
OuterXml: value="novel"
Value: novel
```

**Now, for a document that is in a default namespace**:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<input xmlns='some:Namespace' value='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
                    "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
                    "</input>");

        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "some:Namespace");

        XmlNode value = doc.SelectNodes("//x:input/@value", nsmgr)[0];

        Console.WriteLine("Inner text: " + value.InnerText);
        Console.WriteLine("InnerXml: " + value.InnerXml);
        Console.WriteLine("OuterXml: " + value.OuterXml);
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value.Value);

    }
}
```

**Running this app produces again the wanted results**:

```
Inner text: novel
InnerXml: novel
OuterXml: value="novel"
Value: novel
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not the problem, my doc is Html, and another XPath doe's good, except of that - because this XPath is not right for my intention. I need to find another XPath, but I have no idea.

Comment: Wasn't I was clear? anyway I added **all** my code and wrote what I want: the string: "**10743**" (value of node input)

Comment: @Chanipoz: Have a look at my second update -- a code sample showing exactly how to obtain the value of an attribute using Html Agility Pack-- something you can easily adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 7):

You can also directly grab the attribute if you use the `HtmlNavigator`.

```
//Load document from some html string
HtmlDocument hdoc = new HtmlDocument();
hdoc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

//load navigator for current document
HtmlNavigator navigator = (HtmlNodeNavigator)hdoc.CreateNavigator();

//Get value with given xpath
string xpath = "//input/@value";
string val = navigator.SelectSingleNode(xpath).Value;
```

Comment: THIS is the answer! `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` works the same and allows for very legible XPath one-liners. Thank you, @Pierluc!