# Select meta tag using c#?

Tags: c#

This is Xml where i want to select meta tag

```
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <title>Gmail: Email from Google</title>
              <meta name="description" content="10+ GB of storage, less spam, 
               and mobile access. Gmail is email that&#39;s intuitive, efficient, and
               useful. And maybe even fun.">
              <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="//mail.google.com/favicon.ico">
```

I am doing this

```
            string texturl = textBox2.Text;
            string Url = "http://" + texturl;
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

            var SpanNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");

            if (SpanNodes != null)
            {

                foreach (HtmlNode SN in SpanNodes)
                {

                    string text = SN.InnerText;



                        MessageBox.Show(text);


                }
```

Its not actually selecting any text from there............what i am doing wrong please help

Comment: Show a *short* sample XML doc that can reproduce the problem.  My guess is it's a namespace issue.

Comment: That's not valid XML.

Comment: this is not XML....this is html...source code of a wesite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meta` elements are self-closing elements, meaning they have no text children (InnerText). I believe you want to get the value of the `content` attribute. I believe you do that using something like `SN["content"]`, but I don't know HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Yes i want to get the value of content

Comment: SN.Attributes["content"].Value in place of SN.InnerText should work.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666902/get-a-value-of-an-attribute-by-xpath-and-htmlagilitypack