# xpath expression to select href value from link

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xpath

i have such HTML code

```
<a class="cat" href="/Home/txtdata0/">txtdata0</a>
<a class="cat" href="/Home/txtdata1/">txtdata1</a>
<a class="cat" href="/Home/txtdata2/">txtdata2</a>
<a class="cat" href="/Home/txtdata3/">txtdata3</a>
```

to access to all text of the link i use such XPATH(as in Visual Studio in C#)

`.//a[@class=\"cat\"]`

to access to all href value of the link i use such XPATH(as in Visual Studio in C#)

```
.//a[@class=\"cat\"]/@href
```

Google Chrome Xpath Helper show (**.//a[@class="cat"]** and **.//a[@class="cat"]/@href**)both results correct

```
txtdata0
txtdata1
txtdata2
txtdata3
```

and

```
/Home/txtdata0/
/Home/txtdata1/
/Home/txtdata2/
/Home/txtdata3/
```

Visual Studio with such Xpath  **.//a[@class=\"cat\"]** show:

```
txtdata0
txtdata1
txtdata2
txtdata3
```

and with such Xpath  **.//a[@class=\"cat\"]/@href** show:

```
txtdata0
txtdata1
txtdata2
txtdata3
```

Why second output same as first output?

program code

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(seturl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader readStream = null;

    if (response.CharacterSet == null)
    {
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
    }
    else
    {
        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
    }

    data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

    response.Close();
    readStream.Close();
}

doc.LoadHtml(data);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection bodynode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//a[@class=\"cat\"]");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection bodynod = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//a[@class=\"cat\"]/@href");
MessageBox.Show(bodynode.Count.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(bodynod.Count.ToString());

for (int i = 0; i < bodynode.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(bodynode[i].InnerText.ToString() + " - " + bodynod[i].InnerText.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Looks like HTML Agility Pack cannot match attribute nodes, and returns their parent elements instead. You will need an expert to confirm that, though.

Comment: [Attributes do not have an innerText, only a Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666902/get-a-value-of-an-attribute-by-xpath-and-htmlagilitypack#comment10772717_8666902).

Comment: Thanks Mathias, i added bodynod[i].Attributes["href"].Value.ToString() and it works!

Comment: Glad it worked. take care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I remember correctly HAP attributes can be extracted like this

```
 string _tmpUrl = documentUrl.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='cat']")[i].Attributes["href"].Value;
```